# Passing parameters from jsf page to bean as parameter, and save it

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I've got a web app, based on JSF and managebeans. What i'm trying to do is internet reservation. I've got a BookingGroups, Assortment and Tures - it's from my database, and that works fine. My problem is: How can i save data (objects BookingGroup, Assortment and Tures), while clicking on button and save it untill all data is collected? There are 3 steps: user by clicking on buttons with BookingGroups activates buttons with Assortment etc. I can save a BookingGroup (first object) but then nothing happens. I can display buttons but i cant save objects passed by parameter to the reservationBean.

My jsf page:

Grupy:

```
    <h:form id="Ass">
        <c:forEach var="type" items="#{assortBean.assortList}">
            Asortyment: <h:commandButton value="${type.getName()}"  action="#{rezerwationBean.addAssort(type)}" >
                <f:param name="asid"  value="#{type.replocId}" />
            </h:commandButton> <br></br>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:form>

        <h:form id="Tures">
        <c:forEach var="type" items="#{tureBean.tureList}">
            Tury: <h:commandButton value="${type.getName()}" action="#{rezerwationBean.addTure(type)}" >
               <f:param  name="tureid"  value="#{type.replocId}" />
            </h:commandButton> <br></br>
        </c:forEach>
        </h:form>
```

And my reservationBean:

```
public RezerwationBean() {
    setAssort(null);
    setBgroup(null);
    setTure(null);

}

public String addBG(BookingGroup bg){
    setBgroup(bg);
    System.out.println("Add BG: "+bg.getName());
    return null;
}

public String addAssort(Assortment assort){
    setAssort(assort);
    System.out.println("Add Assort: "+assort.getName());
    return null;
}

public String addTure(Tures ture){
    setTure(ture);
    System.out.println("Add Ture: "+ture.getName());
    return null;
}
```

}

In reservation Bean there are also getters and setters. It's @Dependent bean. I'll be gratefull for any help.

Comment: c:foreach is not encouraged try using ui:repeat instead

Comment: Which JSF specific version? Why do you use `$` for some expressions instead of `#`?

Comment: I've got a JSF 2.2. This $ was in tutorial that i saw couple days ago, it worked so i left it like it is.

Comment: ui:repeat works the same (at surface at least) as a c:foreach. I used c:foreach because of using HashMap - but now i've got just an ArrayList so it works fine.

Comment: @XtremeBiker with `$` you can only read the data from the server (read-only), with `#` you can also write the data to the server (read and write).

Comment: @Bieluus It might help to understand the annotation `@Dependent`. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html

Comment: Ok it works, i've changed action to onClick but, now i cant specify which button was clicked, because it sets all of the object on buttons.

Comment: Actually, lists of comandbuttons(with assortment and tures, bookinggroup buttons are always on)  dissapear  after forward, can u tell me what to do to save them ? I'm out of ideas.